# Targetting user selection from a spinner and using it in next activity - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

I am having a bit of a dilemma at the moment with regards to the best way to target and use what the user has selected from a spinner (drop-down menu) in my application.

To give you some insight, say I have two activities, one called create line which is where the user selects their option from the spinner and the next called line details where I want to be able to work with what the user has selected.

I am currently successfully saving the users drop down selection to an SQLite database.

In my spinner the user can either select the options of 20 or 30. On the line details which is the second activity I want to be able to write an IF statement to tell my `app` to do something depending on whether they have selected 20 or 30?

What is the best method to get the users selections and prepare an IF statement?

- Should I use a db.query to get what the user has selected and use it in an IF statement?

  - Should I store the selection in a `Sharedpreference` and target it that way?

Here is the spinner code:

```
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    quantity.setText("");
                    ;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    quantity.setText(PackageType20);
                    timeadded = 28;
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");


                    break;
                case 2:
                    quantity.setText(PackageType30);
                    timeadded = 27;
                    duration.setText(timeadded + " Hours");

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

EDIT WITH ATTEMPTED METHOD:

CREATE LINE: 
on create line I am storing the users selection in a public static variable:

```
public static spinnerSelection2 = String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
```

LINEDETAILS:
then I am referencing that string on the next activity and setting it to this variable in which I will use in the IF statement:

```
 String spinnerSelection2 = CreateLine.spinnerSelection2;

    if (spinnerSelection2.equals("20")) {
        optimum20 = (int) (diffminutes * 0.383);
        percentage20 = optimum20 / (648 * 100);
    } else if (spinnerSelection2.equals("30"))
            optimum30 = (int) (diffminutes * 0.373);
            percentage30 = optimum30 / (605 * 100);
```

I am not quite sure of what method is the best to use and also unsure of how to do each.. any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that in your switch cases add following lines to go into new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),yourSecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("duration",duration);
intent.putExtra("PackageType", packageType);
```

In your second activity create two strings to store these values. And to import these values there in on create write this :

```
yourVariable = intent.getStringExtra("duration");
yourSecondVariable = intent.getStringExtra("packageType");
```

After that you can apply if else to check which condition satisfies and do operations there accordingly.

Comment: Hope you will get this and make your code to work.If it works for you do let me know or for further assistance text me anytime. And dont forget to mark this post as answer if it works for you. Best of luck :)

Comment: I have tried a different method before seeing your answer. I will update the code I have used above let me know what you think or if this would not work?

Comment: I never used above provided way of yours. If it works then well and good you may stick to it. But the way I told you is a way of getting value from spinner and then passing it to another activity via intent as told in developers forum of android.

Comment: If you want to jump directly to second activity use this code in switch statement cases but if you need to update your ui upon selection then use intent method later when you want to switch to second activity like upon button click etc.

Comment: @TheAlmac2 It is not a good idea to use `static` variables in activity classes. You're better off using the default method of inter activity communication that @M.SaadLakhan suggested

Comment: Okay and how do I reference the intent value to use it in an IF statement like I have tried with my method? e.g. IF intentvalue = "20" {TODO } ?

Comment: Moreover static variables and static methods are not good to use in activity classes for that you need to create singleton class which is another concept and you dont need that for just getting value from spinner and to pass it on to another activity.

Comment: You dont need to compare intent just get value out of intent into another string or variable of your type in second class and then implement your if else statements accordingly.

Comment: @M.saad Lakhan .....  we do not need to bring across any data we just need to know the fact that they have selected either 20 or 30 in the IF statement?

Comment: this is what I m saying just pass your selection like 20 or 30 as int in intent and in next activity apply if statement to compare if its 20 or 30 then implement your logic dependent on that. But you have to pass atleast one element into second activity upon which you can differentiate. You cal also pass boolean value for one if its 20 then a boolean true to next activity or false if its not 20 and check in second activity if bool is true then it means user selected 20 else user selected 30 if received bool from first activity is false.

Comment: just use intents to pass data between activities. It will work buddy :) .Also dont forget to mark this post as answer if it works. Happy coding bro :)

Comment: hey @M.SaadLakhan do you know much about inflating fragments? mine was working but now it is has stopped and giving me a binary error?